# passing a Firehose name as a parameter to a lambda via EventSourceMapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a CloudFormation Template that creates multiple groups of:

- Kinesis Stream
- Firehose
- Lambda function to copy from Kinesis
- and an EventSourceMapping to connect all this

Now I have a problem, I need to know which Firehose shall the lambda function write to. How do I pass the Firehose to the lambda?

Comment: I guess you're using the same `lambda` code in all groups, which in each group it should put the records to a different `Firehose`?

I can't think of a better solution rather than using some name formatting that will map a `Kinesis` instance of name `kinesis-stream-group-1` to a `Firehose` instance of the name `firehose-stream-group-1` or something like that.

When your `lambda` is triggered by `Kinesis` it is provided in the `event` object, to which `Kinesis` stream this record belongs to.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for lambda function environment variables.  Unfortunately, these don't exist.  You're going to need to figure out some kind of a work around.  There are a few hacky ways to do this, but they might not be necessary depending on how you are creating your function.  Are you specifying your code inline in the template, or are you pointing to an s3 bucket?

Comment: I would suggest tag your kinesis stream  something like `aws kinesis add-tags-to-stream ..... `  then in your lambda find desired stream at the runtime.